# Element split-second out of place rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, rendering

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6aBljcPRK78pLegnyL5p

Alright, so the example (in plunker, and also attached as code snippet to this question) is pretty straightforward. There is a div ("button") which can be clicked. When clicked, a loading element is displayed inside it. When the "operation" finishes (replaced by a setTimeout here), the loading element should disappear, and a message area appear above the div.

The effect I'm seeing (and which only occurs if the "operation" finishes as good as immediately) is that the loading element (in my example a Font Awesome icon) is rendered outside the box for a split second.

**NOTE: the loading icon might not be shown at all the first time you click the element. Just use the "Reset" button and click again. For me it's produceable every time.**

Since the display property of both elements are changed at the same time, I would have expected the browser to keep the loading icon inside the box until it would it disappear. This does not, however, seem to be the case.

I've used pure HTML / CSS / Javascript (well, Font Awesome) in order to avoid any bugs / weird behaviour with those.

Is this just how browsers render? Would there be a way to avoid this effect other than using a timeout to delay setting either property (which I consider really ugly for this use case)? I don't believe this is a purely visual effect (my eyes playing a trick on me), but it could be...

I've tried the following to see if anything changed (which it didn't):

- Positioned the icon absolutely inside the ".content" element.
- Replaced the icon with a static `<img>` tag.
- Explicitly hid the icon element, and not just the parent one.

```css
#messageBox {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

#element .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

#element .content .shadow {
  height: 124px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  padding-top: 32px;
  color: #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#element .content .shadow:hover {
  color: #888;
  border-color: #999;
}

#element .content .shadow.inactive {
  color: #bbb;
  border-color: #999;
  cursor: default;
  padding-top: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Positioning plunker</title>

    <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
      window.doSomething = function() {
        var action = document.getElementById('actionButton');
        var icon = document.getElementById('icon');
        var message = document.getElementById('messageBox');

        icon.style.display = "block";

        window.setTimeout(function() {
          message.style.display = 'block';
          icon.style.display = 'none';
        }, 50);
      };
      
      window.reset = function() {
        var action = document.getElementById('actionButton');
        var icon = document.getElementById('icon');
        var message = document.getElementById('messageBox');
        
        action.style.display = 'block';
        icon.style.display = 'none';
        message.style.display = 'none';
      };
    </script>

    <div id="messageBox">Some box containing stuff to push down the content...</div>

    <div id="element">
      <div class="content" style="border:1px solid black; padding: 0">
        <div id="actionButton" class="shadow" onclick="doSomething();">
          <i id="icon" style="display: none" class="fa fa-cog fa-2x text-info"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="reset(); return false;">Reset</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a video and made a slow motion gif from the clicking. I'm pretty sure it's just an optical illusion. Here's eight total frames from the video:

[image: Slowed view of the click]

I saw this first with this. Seems like the classic "Bird in a Cage" illusion.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  icon.style.display = "block";
  message.style.display = "none";
}, 60)

window.setInterval(function() {
  message.style.display = 'block';
  icon.style.display = 'none';
}, 50);
```